# Visual studio code lost Javascript syntax highlight after upgrading to 0.10.10

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Here is my screenshot? How to solve this? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Just confirming: in the lower-right of the status bar-- you're in JavaScript Language Mode?

Comment: Yes. It's JavaScript 1.8.2. The others such as css,html has no syntax highlight problem.

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: Has nothing to do with the theme.

Comment: I got the same issue after upgrading.

Comment: It is fine when I use typescript.

Comment: Still no solution? I delete everything and reinstall still can't solve the issue.

Comment: 0.10.11, still the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem and this is solution worked for me:

Go to `%appdata%\Code\Local Storage` and delete those to files: `file__0.localstorage` and `file__0.localstorage-journal`.

On macOS, the path to the files is

`/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Code/Local Storage`.

Your VS Code settings will be reset to default.

Comment: I closed VS Code, then deleted files and started again. Did you try this?

Comment: Worked for me too (was under `%appdata%\Roaming\Code\Local Storage`).

Comment: On mac, where is it ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me on mac. i found the 2 files but deleting them doesn't solve problem. Files are in /users/USER/Library/Application support/Code

Comment: I'm on mac too. The solution doesn't work for my macbook pro even after I deleted the whole folder and reinstall the vscode. But it works in my iMac.

Comment: This worked for me 2 days ago, but not today when it started happening again.